# Проблема с потоками в java

Tags: java, многопоточность

есть код

```
class SomeThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
            System.out.println(i);

    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeThread test = new SomeThread();
        test.start();

        SomeThread test2 = new SomeThread();
        test2.start();


    }
}
```

в теории должны били вывестись числа от 0 до 9 потоком. Но они выводятся по очереди, с начала первые 10 чисел от 0 до 9, затем следующее 10 чисел от 0 до 9. Подскажите в чём проблема ?

Comment: Проблема в том, что цикл выполняется быстрее, чем запускается второй поток.

Comment: Возможно, если запустить первый поток после того как создастся объект test2, они будут выполняться одновременно. Еще можно добавить нулей к циклу

Comment: я пробовал делать не до 10, а до 1000 - не работает.
Пробовал с начала создавать оба объекта, а только потом и запускать не работает

Comment: Вывод на консоль не блокируется.

Comment: jvm считает очень быстро, попробуй  i < 100000

Answer (score 2):

Причина в неодновременном запуске потоков. Используйте для их синхронного запуска CountDownLatch:

```
private static final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

class SomeThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestString.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeThread test = new SomeThread();
        test.start();

        SomeThread test2 = new SomeThread();
        test2.start();
        countDownLatch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeThread implements Runnable {
    Thread thrd;

    SomeThread(String name){
        thrd = new Thread(this, name);
        thrd.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + thrd.getName());
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                System.out.println("Exception in added thread : " + exc);
            } 
        }
        System.out.println("End thread : " + thrd.getName());
    }
}

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeThread test1 = new SomeThread("test1");

        SomeThread test2 = new SomeThread("test2");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            test1.thrd.join();
            test2.thrd.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException exc) {
            System.out.println("Exception in main thread : " + exc);
        }
    }
}
```

Пару моментов:

- Если в классе реализующем многопоточность не переопределяются методы кроме `run()`, хорошим тоном является расширение интерфейса `Runnable`, в котором объявлен, лишь метод `run()`.
- Результат выполнения многопоточной программы зависит от начинки Вашего пк, в частности от процессора.

Comment: "Хорошим тоном" считается правильно, а главное доходчиво, обьяснять.

Answer (score 0):

Тут нет проблемы. Просто нужно осознавать, что создание потока требует некоторых накладных расходов по времени. В итоге получается ситуация, что Вы создали первый поток, запустили его и только потом создаете второй поток. В итоге, когда второй поток **создался** и Вы запускаете его - первый уже отработал.

Это легко проверить путем увеличения цикла (попробуйте 100, 1000 и тд).

Вариант решения проблемы - сперва создать 2 потока, потом их запустить.

Answer (score 0):

Советую тебе изучить жц потоков.Запуск потока не дает никакую гарантию на то что поток будет работать.У джава есть обработчик потоков он сам определяет какой поток будет выполнятся так же он сам определят когда остановить поток поэтому советую тебе 100 раз перезапустить программу и при запуске программа по разному будет себя вести

Comment: Опачки. А мне всегда говорила, что потоки управляются самой ОС. А можно имя класса планировщика? Ну или какую-либо ссылку, где можно почитать.

Comment: Да конечно прошу , https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071214/java-concurrency/java-101--understanding-java-threads--part-3--thread-scheduling-and-wait-notify.html

Comment: вбейте thread java scheduler

Comment: Забавно, но в Вашей статье написано:
"Java does not force a VM to schedule threads in a specific manner or contain a thread scheduler. That implies platform-dependent thread scheduling."

Answer (score -1):

Ни в чем. У тебя 3 потока: test, test2 и main. main запускает test и идет дальше к `test2.start()`. Если нужно поочередно, вставь следующее после `test.start()`

test.join();

```
public class SomeThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SomeThread test = new SomeThread();
        test.start();
        test.join();
        SomeThread test2 = new SomeThread();
        test2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: вставил, всё равно проблему не решило

Comment: почему у меня работает тогда ??? парвил ответ, смотри код

Comment: можете весь код показать ?

Comment: @ДанилВельдясов правил

Comment: У меня тоже выводит по очереди.

Comment: @ValentineAnzhurov, потому что вы решаете не ту проблему, очевидно.

Answer (score -2):

Может дело в том что у `println` есть так же своя внутренняя синхронизация, и его просто захватывает потом в цикле и не отпускает до окончания цикла. Плюс к тому, код может выполняется быстрее чем приходит прерывание и выкидывает его из ядра.

```
public void println(int x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет. Синхронизация нужна только для того чтобы не было гонки, то есть для того чтобы исключить возможность, когда оба потока одновременно пишут данные.